# Will a cisco Router relay NTP information to a Checkpoint firewall?

Tags: cisco, router, firewall, ntp, checkpoint

so i have a checkpoint firewall and a cisco router , cisco router clock os synchronized via a public NTP server,  as we know,  a route which a ntp client can also relay the ntp information,  will it relay it to checkpoint or any other vendor devices?

Comment: Yes, it can be an ntp server. (in fact, it is by default.)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have it slightly backwards actually. The NTP source, such as your router, doesn't actively relay anything of its own initiative. It can however act as a time server for other devices, and it doesn't care whether said devices are Cisco, Checkpoint, or whatever so long as they present themselves as well-behaved standards-compliant NTP clients.

You'll need to activate the NTP server functionality through a command such as :

```
ntp master [stratum]
```

The stratum is usually one more than the stratum of the time server your router is getting its NTP information from.